# Connecting to mysql database from VB.NET

Tags: .net, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, connection

I'm having some trouble setting up a working connection to a mysql database from Visual Studio 2010.
After downloading and installing the mysql-net connector, I set up a simple testing database in Xampp and experimented around a bit until I managed to read some values from the database and inserting new ones.

Now I'm trying to access another database on a remote server and all I get is an error message:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Basically, I'm only trying to execute this code:

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=111.11.111.111;Uid=root;Pwd=mypwd;Database=mydb;")
con.Open()
con.Close()
```

(server ip looks a bit different of course)

When I access my local database, it looks quite similar:

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=;Database=test;")
con.Open()
con.Close()
```

Nevertheless, I can access the remote database easily using a simple PHP script... no problems there.

Any ideas how to fix this? :-/

Comment: Can you ping the IP? Possibly there are connection problems due to the ‚uncommon‘ subnet

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for MySql on [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/mysql), it looks like the default port is 3306.

Make sure the firewalls on the machines and between them allow traffic through this port.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use connection string like this -

```
Host=host_name;User Id=root;Port=3306;Database=test;Password=pwd
```

Specify values you need - host name, port, password...